# expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'sizeof'

Tags: objective-c

```
@implementation classname

static const unsigned int OFFSET_STX =0;
static const unsigned int OFFSET_ETX =1;
static const unsigned int OFFSET_KTX =2;
static const unsigned int OFFSET_MTX =4;
static const unsigned int OFFSET_LTX =5;

static const char STX =0x05;
static const char ETX =0x09;

@end
```

Error:

```
expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'sizeof'
```

How do i declare these static variables inside the class.

Do i need to declare

```
+(int)OFFSET_ETX
{
 return OFFSET_ETX=0;
}
```

and call through [classname OFFSET_ETX]; for every static variables.
I am having more than 10 static variables to be assigned in my program.

Comment: possible duplicate of [error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before ' 'foo'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/990906/iphone-error-expected-asm-or-attribute-before-foo) or [Objective-C error expected asm or attribute before class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825597/)

Comment: @Josh Caswell:My question is different from both the two links.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot put a static variable inside a class interface in Objective C.  In Objective C, `static` has the same meaning as it does in C.  Do this instead:

```
enum {
    OFFSET_STX = 0,
    OFFSET_ETX = 1,
    OFFSET_KTX = 2,
    OFFSET_MTX = 3,
    OFFSET_LTX = 4
};

@implementation classname
...
@end
```

Comment: its static const unsigned int.Will it cause any problem as enum will hold const int and not unsigned int and i'm also having 5 and more declarations like this "static const char STX = 0x01".Its also showing me the same error.I cant declare that inside enum isnt it.

Comment: Static variables may only appear at file scope or inside functions.  You can't put them inside classes, structs, or enums.  And `0x01` is a perfectly fine value to put in an enum -- a `char` constant will get upconverted to an `int` or `unsigned int` when you use it anyway.