# Strange CoreData compile error

Tags: iphone, core-data, compiler-errors

My project can't be compiled today suddenly, the error is at

CoreDataDefines.h

```
COREDATA_EXTERN double NSCoreDataVersionNumber;
```

The error info is

/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/Headers/CoreDataDefines.h:71: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '**attribute**' before 'extern'

I don't know how this happen. Because this file belongs to the SDK, i can't modify it.

I have tried clean, etc, but no use.

can someone help?

Comment: I create another empty project with CoreData in, it is fine. just for this project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well, I saw this post

[Objective-C error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'class'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825597/objective-c-error-expected-asm-or-attribute-before-class)

it actually has nothing to do with CoreData, I just mistakely typed a character in the very beginning of a class header file who import CoreData.

removed that character, everything is fine

Comment: Thanks, I accidentally typed a `*` in `main.m` and that was causing the problem...